# Define 0 folders found to execute a subprocess

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

How can I define that 0 (number zero) folders are located within the current directory?. I´m asking this due to within a batch program, I cant make that this condition be true in order to go to nofolder subprocess.

```
@echo off
set count=
for /d %%a in (*) do set /a count+=1
if %count%==0 (goto nofolder) else (goto display)
:nofolder
cls
echo No folders found
pause
goto end
:display
cls
echo One or more folders found
pause
goto end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%count%==0` will never be true because count is never set to zero.

Change `set count=` to `set "count=0"`

Comment: @frantika  Glad to help.